# How to get build list for particular Commit through DevOps REST API

Tags: rest, azure-devops

I need to retrieve a list of builds associated with particular Commit (see a picture of TFS UI) through Azure DevOps REST API. I can do it by using brute force:

1. Load all builds for my repository through [API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1). Cannot find here a filter for commit:

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds`

2. Then filter-out only builds with specified `"commitId": "eed1b008520c2b32669bef9a0a08be8a50b6e8a4"`

But this is extremely inefficient solution. Can you help me if there is a more efficient way? I tried to load details for Commit with links, but there is no link to build or builds.

[image: List of builds in Azure DevOps UI]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [Statuses API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/statuses/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) for Commit. It seems that when starting and ending build, the appropriate status is posted.

So when I call 
`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}/statuses?api-version=5.1`

I get all last builds associated with the Commit and their statuses.

Thanks to Hugh Lin for showing me direction..

Comment: is it possible to do it when azure pipeline is link to a private github repository ?

Comment: @victorgallet Sure, the only difference is in base URL format, the REST API is the same. In fact, I DO it with private repository

Comment: Can you show me how you achieve it ? Because I can't have my github repository listed using Repository API. Thx

Comment: @victorgallet Maybe there is some misunderstanding here? Do you mean *Git repository in TFS on promises* (this is my case) or real GitHub repository? The second option I do not know at all.

Comment: Yes, it's the second option. I can tell you it does not work and I clearly don't understand how Azure Pipeline do the join with its repositories and a Github repository

Comment: @victorgallet But in this case also it should be possible, because Azure DevOps UI itself uses Azure REST Api for its data access. So you only need to get the right URL. You can use a debugger and catch API call, as described in Hugh Lin - MSFT ansver.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no other ways to get builds for particular commit through the rest api except for retrieval via commitId.
We can't filter the returned result with the commitId or sourceVersion as parameters.

If you feel that getting all the builds and then filtering through the commitId is extremely inefficient, the easiest way to do it in UI: In Commits, you query the specified commit through commitId. In the pipeline status tab of this commit, all relevant builds are displayed. As shown in your figure, you can click on a specific build to jump to the detailed page of the build.

Another challenging way is to press `F12` in the browser then select `Network` to capture the request. You can capture the buildId in the response body, and then you can get the builds with rest api based on the buildId.

You need to write script to parse the buildId from `"targetUrl":"vstfs:///Build/Build/xxx"`

[image]