# How to retrieve build by commit?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I have a PR which was merged with `commit XXX`. Is it possible to get build by the commit?

I found similar question - [How to get build list for particular Commit through DevOps REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123660/how-to-get-build-list-for-particular-commit-through-devops-rest-api)

but statuses for my commit are empty. Could you please help me to get right solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such api to get build by the commit, you could submit a suggestion at website below:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21

Currently, you need to filter `sourceVersion` (commitID) parameter from [Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) api to get the build list.

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?